# Degrees of freedom due to treatment

Tags: anova, experiment-design, degrees-of-freedom, blocking

let $a$ be the number of treatments.

In Randomized Complete Block Design(RCBD), degrees of  freedom due to treatment is $(a-1) $
.

let $k$ be the number of treatments exactly in each block in a Balanced Incomplete Block Design(BIBD).

In BIBD, Adjusted Mean Square  due to treatment is given by  adjusted  sum of square  due to treatment  divide by degrees of freedom $(a-1) $.

But my question is why do we divide it by $
 (a-1) $? .Since it is adjusted  ,  why don’t  we divide it by $(k-1) $?

Comment: In mean square error of treatment we pooled the effect of treatments thats why it is $a-1$. and $k-1$ is the degree of freedom of block, here we are interested in block effect.

Comment: @Azeem But The degree of freedom is not $k-1$. It is $b-1$ so written on the book.$b$ = number of blocks & $k$ is defined above.

Comment: In your stated example $b & k$ are equal, thats why I say that.

Comment: @Azeem I apologize. I forgot to mention $k<b$

Comment: Keep in mind general rule of degree of freedom that is $n-k-1$ where $n$ denotes number whose effect is to be tested, $k$ is number of parameters estimated (here is zero).